# Are repotted plants having transplant shock better kept in shade?

Tags: plant-care, transplanting, repotting

Is it better to keep them in the shade till the plant recovers? Or should they be shown sunlight? Assuming you don't know how much sunlight the plant got before being repotted.

Edit: Added images

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of plant is it?

Comment: It is a curry leaf plant, Murraya koenigii

Answer (score 1):

If the plant is dying, definitely put it in the shade. Giving it some potassium sulfate can also help.

If the plant is just shocked, and not getting damaged further, I wouldn't bother putting it in the shade (but potassium should still help). Losing leaves could be a sign that it wants less sun, though. Wilting is such a sign.

Sometimes removing the oldest leaves can help. That's a lot like shading the plant, without actually moving it. New growth can handle transplant shock better if the old growth is gone. At least, that's true for tomatoes. Not all species of plants are the same.

Okay, now that I know it's a curry leaf plant, it appears that [it's normal for them to be shocked for a while when repotting](https://pinchofseeds.com/how-to-plant-a-curry-leaf-plant/#:%7E:text=The%20Curry%20Leaf%20Plant%20doesn,leaf%20plant%20only%20when%20needed.) (but ideally, you shouldn't repot them, or any plant, when the sun is shining, especially the afternoon and late morning sun, especially if the UV index is very far above 0). I've never grown a curry leaf plant, but I would suggest gradually reintroducing it to stronger sun when it's ready. Doing it all at once might be bad, if it's been in the shade too long. Apparently, they like a lot of sun. However, if you were to risk doing it all at once, I'd suggest doing it at about 6 PM or later.

I'm not sure how curry leaf plants respond to potassium supplementation. So, I would be conservative in the amount.

Comment: Some leaves have fallen, does that mean it is dying?

Comment: Adding a photo.

Comment: I have kept it in shade for 5 days.

Comment: I don't know how near death it is, as I'm not familiar with this species, but based on that fact, I would recommend keeping it out of the sun for a good while. If it's not dead yet, there's a chance. If it were a tomato, five days would be quite more than enough. The wilting leaves mean it's still in shock. It's more sensitive than a tomato, it seems. Does that water drain?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The water does drain, and the nursery guy has supplemented the soil with some potash.